maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas for flashbot's
I'm trying to rescue my vesting rewards with flashbot's and my bundle has 3 transaction's but i'm always to late with this code.
const gasTransaction = {
transaction: {
from: "0xbc808B.....",
to: "0x7c65e4e.....",
value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.006"), //0.006ETH
type: 2,
maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas,
maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
gasLimit: 21000,
chainId: 1,
nonce: newNonce
},
signer: safeWallet
};
//
const claimTransaction = {
  transaction: {
    to: "0x4f2bC...",
    data: "0xc8fd6ed000000000",
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
    gasLimit: 115000,
    chainId: 1,       
    nonce: haNonce
  },
  signer: haWallet
};

//
const transferTransaction =   {
  transaction: {
    to: tokenContractAddress, 
    data: "0xa9059cbb00000000000",
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: feeData.maxFeePerGas,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
    gasLimit: 56000, 
    chainId: 1,
    nonce: haNonce + 1  
  },
  signer: haWallet
};

so i changed it to
   const gasTransaction = {
  transaction: {
    from: "0xbc808B.....",
    to: "0x7c65e4e.....",
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.006"), //0.006ETH
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('50','gwei'),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('40','gwei'),
    gasLimit: 21000,
    chainId: 1,
    nonce: newNonce
  },
  signer: safeWallet 
};

//
const claimTransaction = {
  transaction: {
    to: "0x4f2bC...",
    data: "0xc8fd6ed000000000",
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('50','gwei'),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('40','gwei'),
    gasLimit: 115000,
    chainId: 1,       
    nonce: haNonce
  },
  signer: haWallet
};

//
const transferTransaction =   {
  transaction: {
    to: tokenContractAddress, 
    data: "0xa9059cbb00000000000",
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('50','gwei'),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits('40','gwei'),
    gasLimit: 56000, 
    chainId: 1,
    nonce: haNonce + 1  
  },
  signer: haWallet
};

will this help to include my bundle in the next possible block?
are 50 gwei to much with the current gas price ?
